# add shortcode support in customizer

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-customizer

How to add `shortcode` support in Customizer live preview. I have implemented the live preview using transport `postMessage` but, It just reflect the HTML as it is.

I think I need to use `selective_refresh` to work shortcode in customizer preview.

I have no idea how to get current HTML in `selective_refresh`.

Check below code snippet.

---

*Step: 1* - Add panel, section, setting ( with `'transport' => 'postMessage'` ) and control.

```
/**
 * Add panel
 */
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'my-sample-panel', array(
    'title'    => __( 'Sample Panel', 'next' ),
) );

/**
 * Add section
 */
$wp_customize->add_section( 'my-sample-section', array(
    'title'    => __( 'Sample Section', 'next' ),
    'panel'    => 'my-sample-panel',
) );

/**
 * Add setting
 */
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'my-sample-text-option', array(
    'default'   => '',
    'type'      => 'option',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
) );

/**
 * Add control
 */
$wp_customize->add_control( 'my-sample-text-option', array(
    'section'        => 'my-sample-section',
    'label'          => __( 'Text / HTML', 'next' ),
    'type'           => 'textarea',
) );
```

*Step: 2* - Customizer `customizer-preview.js`.

```
( function( $ ) {

    /**
     * Text / HTML
     */
    wp.customize( 'my-sample-text-option', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( new_value ) {
            jQuery( '.custom-html-section' ).html( new_value );
        } );
    } );

} )( jQuery );
```

*Step: 3* - Front end HTML

```
<div class="custom-html-section"></div>
```

---

Above code snippet replace HTML as it is in the target selector.

I'm tried `Partial support` by avoiding `Step: 2`

## Partial support

```
/**
 * Add partial refresh
 */
if ( isset( $wp_customize->selective_refresh ) ) {

    $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'my-sample-text-option', array(
        'selector'            => '.custom-html-section',
        'container_inclusive' => false,
        'render_callback'     => function() {
            return get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
        },
    ) );
}
```

---

Here, I use the `get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' )` It's showing the blog name as expected.

But, How can I get the current HTML and from the `setting` and apply `do_shortcode`?

Expected like this:

```
'render_callback'     => function() {
    return do_shortcode( $UPDATED_CONTROL_CONTENTS ); // Expect like this to work shortcode in customizer.
    // return get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I was not understand how to get the updated customizer contents in `$UPDATED_CONTROL_CONTENTS` variable within the `selective_refresh`.

---

I used `type => option` for the setting. So, It store the date in `option` name `my-sample-text-option`.

So, Using `get_option()` I'm able to get the update options from customizer.

---

#### Solution:

```
/**
 * Add partial refresh
 */
if ( isset( $wp_customize->selective_refresh ) ) {

    $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'my-sample-text-option', array(
        'selector'            => '.custom-html-section',
        'container_inclusive' => false,
        'render_callback'     => function() {

            // Get update data from option `my-sample-text-option` using funcition get_option()
            $options = get_option( `my-sample-text-option` );
            return do_shortcode( $options );

        },
    ) );
}
```